# Shared Entities between Frontend and Backend Bundles in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, entity, bundle, separation-of-concerns, symfony-3.3

In a typical web application, according to the [Separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle, and as ***frontend*** and ***backend*** sections, have almost complete set of different

- Forms
- Exceptions
- Views
- Controllers

I decided my Symfony web application to have separate *Bundles* for ***Frontend*** and ***Backend*** (and ***API*** later).

The problem is with **Entities**, as they could be used in common. But I dont know how to reasonably structure my application.

I think of:

```
src
|---AppBundle
|---FrontendBundle
|---BackendBundle
```

and

```
src
|---AppBundle
    |---FrontendBundle
    |---BackendBundle
```

and

```
src
|---FrontendBundle
|---BackendBundle
```

Each with some pros and cons. But I don't know how to share the **Entities** across the bundles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After months deeping into **Symfony Bundles** and other well-defined concepts & components like **Symfony Components**, I am posting this answer for any further reference to this question for those with similar problem:

## What should be considered as a Bundle?

[Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles.html) says:

- A bundle is **similar to a plugin** in other software
- Bundles are **first-class citizens** in Symfony
- You may use pre-built features packaged in **third-party bundles**
- You may distribute your **own bundles**
- You may pick and **choose which features to enable** in your application

[There are two types](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html) of bundles:

- **Application-specific bundles**: only used to build your application (reside in `src` directory)
- **Reusable bundles**: meant to be shared across many projects. (reside in `vendor` directory)

## What to do now?

So, as of now, I design my application structure like this:

My **Bundle** is not going to be **Reusable**, and it is **Application-specific**, so it is going to reside in `src` directory.

There is no need to separate BackendBundle and FrontendBundle, because they are **tightly coupled**. So:

- I will have only AppBundle (or what ever better name chosen for it) under `src`
- To separate **Backend** & **Frontend** functionality, I use **namespaces**:

  ```
  \src\AppBundle\Controller\Backend\UserController
  \src\AppBundle\Controller\Frontend\UserController
  ```

  or

  ```
  \src\AppBundle\Form\Backend\UserType
  \src\AppBundle\Form\Frontend\UserType
  ```
- **Entities** are shared between **Backend** & **Frontend** thus reside in:

  ```
  \src\AppBundle\Entity
  ```
- **Business Logic** like:

  - Any DTO (Data Transfer Object)
  - Any Data Handler (to manipulate the model data)
  - Any Repository class or similar classes
  - Any Utility and helper class (to help manipulate model data)
  - Any Interfaces related to model data

  reside in:

  ```
  \src\AppBundle\Model
  ```

This pattern, can be used for other things like **views** & **exceptions** too.

```
src
|
└---AppBundle
    |
    |---Controller
    |   |
    |   |---Backend
    |   |   |
    |   |   └---UserController
    |   |
    |   └---Frontend
    |       |
    |       └---UserController
    |
    |---Entity
    |
    |---Form
    |   |
    |   └---Backend
    |   |   |
    |   |   └---UserType
    |   |
    |   └---Frontend
    |       |
    |       └---UserType
    |
    └---Model
        |
        |---Repository
        |
        └---Handler
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first structure but under the same Namespace ,
like :

```
src
    |---App
         |---ApiBundle
         |---FrontendBundle
         |---BackendBundle
```

Also , why would you want entities in the frontendBundle ? And I am sure you can access the entities of backendBundle from the ApiBundle thru Entity Manager .

You can use this in each bundle :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->getRepository(Tasks::class)->findAll();
```

Comment: @Trix But you still can have all the entities in the backendBundle .

Comment: *The* `generate:doctrine:crud` *command generates a basic controller for a given entity located in a given bundle.*

Comment: @Trix I recommend to make your own CRUD and not generating it :)) I don't know if by using that command you can choose where the views to generate .

Comment: @Trix You made me curious so I think I'll try making it wen I arrive at home.
**Try making your own command , if you search in all the framework there is a file  `GenerateDoctrineCrudCommand.php`  , that is the command made by**  _Fabien_ **, you can take the functionality and paste it in your command and modify it by your needs , I think it's a pretty stuff to do , I hope you succeed .**